# Counting top level items in a custom menu walker

Tags: menus, walker

I am creating a split menu (half the items on the left, logo in the middle, remaining items on the right). I don't really understand Walkers all that well, but I found [this code snippet](https://gist.github.com/RevConcept/c3887ad018a667fe5a41).

This was working well for me until my client wanted to add child items. The current code is counting all the menu items (10) when I want it to just count the top level items (currently 7).

How do I adjust this code so that it only counts the top level items?

```
class Split_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    var $current_menu = null;
    var $break_point  = null;

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args, $id=0) {

        global $wp_query;

        if( !isset( $this->current_menu ) )
            $this->current_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $args->menu );

        if( !isset( $this->break_point ) )
            $this->break_point = ceil( $this->current_menu->count / 2 ) + 1;

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        if( $this->break_point == $item->menu_order )
            $output .= $indent . '</li></ul><ul><li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
        else
            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculation you talking about going here:

```
if( !isset( $this->break_point ) )
        $this->break_point = ceil( $this->current_menu->count / 2 ) + 1;
```

You can't get top-level items count this way. Instead you should count it yourself. You can do this using [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items). Every top-level item should have menu_item_parent set to '0'.

You should create additional variable where you calculate already displayed elements. So top of your file should looks like this:

```
class Split_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    public $break_point = null;
    public $displayed = 0; 

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args, $id=0) {

    global $wp_query;

    if( !isset( $this->break_point ) ) {
        $menu_elements = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $args->menu );
        $top_level_elements = 0;

        foreach( $menu_elements as $el ) {
            if( $el->menu_item_parent === '0' ) {
                $top_level_elements++;
            }
        }
        $this->break_point = ceil( $top_level_elements / 2 ) + 1;
     }   


    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
...
...
...
```

Then you should increment `$this->displayed++;` every time you display top level element (for example at the end of start_el() function):

```
if( $item->menu_item_parent === '0' ) {
    $this->displayed++;
}
```

Lastly instead of

```
if( $this->break_point == $item->menu_order )
```

you should use

```
if( $this->break_point == $this->displayed )
```

Comment: Thank you! This is now getting the correct break point, but since it is using if( $this->break_point == $item->menu_order ) to check if it's  it's splitting it within a submenu. Is there a way to make sure that it only splits at a parent level?

Comment: You can do this exactly the same way. Just check if $item has menu_item_parent set to '0', so something like this:
if( $this->break_point == $item->menu_order && $item->menu_item_parent === '0' )

Comment: This is the logic I initially thought of, however since it reaches the break point at a submenu, it just skips now and doesn't put the split in at all. The logic I'm thinking of is "If the break point has been reached and it's a parent item, put the break in. Else, continue on until the submenu has closed, then put the break in". I'm just not sure how to write this logic into the walker.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer, so now i think it's complete. If it helped you please mark this answer as correct. :)

Comment: I modified my code, but it's showing the way that it did in the beginning. I have the following menu structure:
Parent
Parent
- Child
- Child
- Child
Parent
Parent
Parent
Parent
Parent

And it's splitting after the third child.

Here is my updated code: http://pastebin.com/K7xan2qM

Comment: You increment $this->displayed every time you display any element, and you should increment it only for top-level elements, so before incrementing you need to check if current item is top level item. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm unsure of what you  mean by every time you display any element.  I put it at the end of start_el but I'm not sure where else it needs to go.

Comment: See updated answer. It can be at bottom of the function, but it should be like that:

`if( $item->menu_item_parent === '0' ) {
    $this->displayed++;
}`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But I had to change 
$this->break_point = ceil( $top_level_elements / 2 ) + 1; to 

$this->break_point = ceil( $top_level_elements / 2 );

Comment: I know this is super old, but it's still a usable code snippet, however if the item it's breaking on has children it will apply your $output after the item but also after the children of that item in the dropdown so you should check that it's only the top level something like 
if( $this->break_point == $this->displayed && $depth == 0 )